# Print every line of file, last to first, with recursion

Tags: java, recursion, comparative-review, file

Had a discussion with a friend to solve this extra credit problem, and we came up with two separate solutions. What are the differences between these two? Is one better than the other? How can I make this code better?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExtraCredit {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int count = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("src/ExtraCredit.java"));
        recursiveCountEveryOtherLine(count, scan);
        scan = new Scanner(new File("src/ExtraCredit.java"));
        System.out.println("***SECOND METHOD***");
        recursiveScannerExploit(scan);
    }
    // Write a method called from main that prints
    // every other line of this file from last to first
    // use recursion NO LOOPS!!
    // print line 10, 8, 6, 4, 2

    public static void recursiveCountEveryOtherLine(int count, Scanner scan) {
        count++;
        if (!scan.hasNextLine()) {
            scan.close();
            return;
        } else if (count % 2 == 0) {
            String temp = scan.nextLine();
            recursiveCountEveryOtherLine(count, scan);
            System.out.println(count + " " + temp);

        } else {
            scan.nextLine();
            recursiveCountEveryOtherLine(count, scan);
        }
    }

    public static void recursiveScannerExploit(Scanner scan) {
        if (closeScanner(scan)) {
            return;
        }
        String tempGarbage = scan.nextLine(); // Used to pop an element off the scanner
        if (closeScanner(scan)) {
            return;
        }
        String temp = scan.nextLine();
        recursiveScannerExploit(scan);
        System.out.println(temp);
    }

    public static boolean closeScanner(Scanner scan) {
        if (!scan.hasNextLine()) {
            scan.close();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I get started I just want to mention that you have two unused imports:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
```

Now I'll address your questions:

> What are the differences between these two?

Virtually nothing other than the obvious:

Method #1 depends on a counter parameter to decide whether or not the line should be printed whereas the method #2 does not. This makes method #1 a little awkward to read, but anyone who understands recursion (which is any good programmer) should catch on to what you're doing. Having the counter could use slightly more memory but it's unlikely something this small would have any impact on overall performance and it's generally not worthwhile to optimize something like this unless you have measured your program's performance and determined there is a trouble spot.

Method #2 depends on calling the `closeScanner` method twice, and invoking a method may carry a bit of overhead cost. However you really don't need to concern yourself with this unless you have measured the performance of your code and find that there is a problem. (See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6495030/3284624))

> Is one better than the other?

Again, the two are so similar there isn't really an objective way to say with certainty which is "better". If I had to select one I would probably prefer method #2 as I think it would more straightforward for someone else to use. It doesn't require knowledge of recursion or passing a counter initialized to the correct value.

> How can I make this code better?

In general comment your code so that others recognize its intended purpose and expected inputs and outputs. [Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html) is a good way to do this. Something else you can do is modify your method(s) to return something (e.g. `String`) rather than printing to `System.out` so that you can write automated tests against them more easily.

**Method #1:**

`else if (count % 2 == 0) {` does not need to have the `else` since you would have returned from the method if there is no next line.

When you call this method you don't need a counter reference in `main`, so instead just directly pass the value of `count` like this:

`recursiveCountEveryOtherLine(0, scan);`

**Method #2:**

Replace this line: `String tempGarbage = scan.nextLine();`
with this: `scan.nextLine();` as you have no reason to keep a reference to the lines you aren't going to print.

Inside of the `closeScanner` method you have:

```
else {
    return false;
}
```

you can simply write `return false` without the `else` since you would have returned `true` earlier if there is no next line.

Answer (score 1):

Good code should not hold surprises. When I start by reading the method name "recursiveCountEveryOtherLine" I expect it to ignore a line, then handle that "other line". This is exactly what the second implementation does. But that one has a different name (perhaps just to distinguish it from the first to post here?).
So my prefered solution would be the method name of the first, with the implementation of the second one.

The first solution works a bit differently. It sees the "odd line" and "even line" as separate steps. This could also work but I would implement that with 2 different methods that call each other as the recursion step. We can also go a step further and add an extra initial method to handle starting with the correct count value and closing the scanner. That would then look something like this:

```
public static void recursivePrintEveryOtherLine(Scanner scan){
    helperPrintOddCase(1, scan);
    scan.close();
}

private static void helperPrintOddCase(int count, Scanner scan){
    if (!scan.hasNextLine()) {
        return;
    }
    scan.nextLine();
    helperPrintEvenCase(count + 1, scan);
}

private static void helperPrintEvenCase(int count, Scanner scan) {
    if (!scan.hasNextLine()) {
        return;
    }
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(count + " " + line);
    helperPrintOddCase(count + 1 , scan);
}
```

Note that I kept the count mostly because I like that the solution printed the line number as well. And to point out that it reads more natural to do that "+1" in the call to the next step. That way the method call handles the count that is passed to it, not the step after that.

---

#### recursion is bad (in java)

I want to point out that java doesn't handle recursion too well. To test this try running this simple program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    recursionLimitTest(0);
}

private static void recursionLimitTest(int i) {
    System.out.println(i);
    recursionLimitTest(i+1);
}
```

For me this crashed with a StackOverflowError after printing 11402.
This gets worse the more memory is used inside the method, and for the parameters. For example adding some String like this:

```
private static void recursionLimitTest(int i, String str) {
    System.out.println(i);
    String temp = "something" + i;
    recursionLimitTest(i+1, temp);
}
```

reduced the reached call to 9652.

This might be more than enough for your assignment but it's worth trying to replace recursion with loops in java. In this case it's relatively easy:

```
public static void printEveryOtherLine(Scanner scan){
    int count = 0;
    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        count++;
        if(count%2 != 0){
            //ignore odd lines
            scan.nextLine();
        } else{
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println(count + " " +line);
        }
    }
    scan.close();
}
```

Recursion does have its uses (traversing trees comes to mind), but outside of academic assignments it's better to try to avoid them in java.

(Side note: some languages like scala do have tail-recursion optimisation. In that case using recursion might be easier to read than loops).